# How to display data using DataTable fetched data from API?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I have data fetched form API. I want to display it into the DataTable.

The data is fetched from the API and it got displayed into the DataTable but I have problem in displaying the data. The data is displayed but it also give me

> No data available in table

[image]

below is what I have tried

```
<div class="nk-block nk-block-lg">
  <div class="nk-block-head">
    <div class="nk-block-head-content">
      <h4 class="nk-block-title">Data </h4>
      <div class="nk-block-des">
        <p>Policy</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-preview">
    <div class="card-inner">
      <table class="datatable-init table" id="datatable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Module</th>
            <th>Policy & Terms of Services Details</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="dataDetails">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .card-preview -->
</div>
<!-- nk-block -->
```

```
< script >


  let cnt = 1;


$(document).ready(function() {

  getList();

})

const getList = () => {
    axios.get(`${url}getList`)
      .then(function(res) {
        if (res.data.status == 'success') {
          res.data.result.map((e) => {

            if (e.role_id == '3') {

              $("#dataDetails").append(` 
                            <tr>
                                <td>${cnt++}</td>
                                <td>${e.name}</td>
                                <td><a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="detail('${e.id}')">${e.title}</a></td>
                            </tr>

                        `


              );
            }
          })
        }
      })
  }

  <
  /script>
```

How do I fix the problem ? Because inside the table have data, but it keep displaying the `No data available in table`

after adding the `$("#datatable").DataTable();`  inside the `const`

```
 $("#dataDetails").append(` 
                            <tr>
                                <td>${cnt++}</td>
                                <td>${e.name}</td>
                                <td><a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="detail('${e.id}')">${e.title}</a></td>
                            </tr>

                        `
               $("#datatable").DataTable(); 

              );
```

I got error with `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`
[image]

showing at this line

[image]